# Abrupt error when trying to run model with viewshed as batch process

Tags: error, qgis-modeler, batch, viewshed, vectorization

I am trying to run the following model as a batch process. In summary, I take a DEM raster layer and a number of individual points as separate .gpkg files in a directory (these points have been created using the 'Create viewpoints' function in the [Visibility Analysis plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ViewshedAnalysis/). I then generate the binary viewshed of each point, vectorize it into a polygon, dissolve it based on the visibility parameter (1 or 0) and extract only the visible (1) areas and save the resulting polygon in another directory.

[image: viewshed analysis model]

When trying to run the model as a batch process on both QGIS 3.32.0 RC and QGIS 3.28.8 LTR, the first few files run successfully and generate the correct result. For example,

```
Processing algorithm 1/865…
Algorithm site_viewshed_vector_generation starting…
Input parameters:
{"dem":"C:/Users/Work/Projects/Building_Cover_Affected_Sites/data/processed/Building_Elevation_Combined_DEM.tif","site_viewpoints":"C:/Users/Work/Projects/Building_Cover_Affected_Sites/data/processed/Site_Viewpoints/CM0001.gpkg","visible_viewshed":"C:/Users/Work/Projects/Building_Cover_Affected_Sites/data/processed/Site_Viewsheds/view_CM0001.gpkg"}

Model processed OK. Executed 4 algorithm(s) total in 97.32 s.
Algorithm site_viewshed_vector_generation correctly executed…
Execution completed in 97.329 seconds
Results:
{"CHILD_INPUTS":{"native:dissolve_1":{"FIELD":["VIEW"],"INPUT":"Vector_polygons_1a077f13_d80b_4dd9_b32c_d52219f44cf6","OUTPUT":"memory:Dissolved","SEPARATE_DISJOINT":false},"native:extractbyexpression_1":{"EXPRESSION":"\"VIEW\" = 1","INPUT":"Dissolved_0b4b1672_183f_4328_b1bd_ba125a739201","OUTPUT":""},"native:pixelstopolygons_1":{"FIELD_NAME":"VIEW","INPUT_RASTER":"C:/Users/Work/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ukeBuJ/9a76815a7ac84c2e8e472e8aa9f087f4/OUTPUT.tif","OUTPUT":"memory:Vector polygons","RASTER_BAND":"1"},"visibility:viewshed_1":{"ANALYSIS_TYPE":0,"DEM":"Building_Elevation_Combined_DEM_9e501972_ac6d_4f8a_90bd_30cfdd5fc8c0","OBSERVER_POINTS":"C:/Users/Work/Projects/Building_Cover_Affected_Sites/data/processed/Site_Viewpoints/CM0001.gpkg","OPERATOR":0,"OUTPUT":"C:/Users/Work/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ukeBuJ/9a76815a7ac84c2e8e472e8aa9f087f4/OUTPUT.tif","REFRACTION":0.13,"USE_CURVATURE":true}},"CHILD_RESULTS":{"native:dissolve_1":{"OUTPUT":"Dissolved_0b4b1672_183f_4328_b1bd_ba125a739201"},"native:extractbyexpression_1":{"OUTPUT":"C:/Users/Work/Projects/Building_Cover_Affected_Sites/data/processed/Site_Viewsheds/view_CM0001.gpkg"},"native:pixelstopolygons_1":{"OUTPUT":"Vector_polygons_1a077f13_d80b_4dd9_b32c_d52219f44cf6"},"visibility:viewshed_1":{"OUTPUT":"C:/Users/Work/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ukeBuJ/9a76815a7ac84c2e8e472e8aa9f087f4/OUTPUT.tif"}},"visible_viewshed":"C:/Users/Work/Projects/Building_Cover_Affected_Sites/data/processed/Site_Viewsheds/view_CM0001.gpkg"}
```

However, after a certain point it starts to fail with the following message:

```
Processing algorithm 12/865…
Algorithm site_viewshed_vector_generation starting…
Input parameters:
{"dem":"C:/Users/Work/Projects/Building_Cover_Affected_Sites/data/processed/Building_Elevation_Combined_DEM.tif","site_viewpoints":"C:/Users/Work/Projects/Building_Cover_Affected_Sites/data/processed/Site_Viewpoints/CM0024.gpkg","visible_viewshed":"C:/Users/Work/Projects/Building_Cover_Affected_Sites/data/processed/Site_Viewsheds/view_CM0024.gpkg"}

Error encountered while running Viewshed
Algorithm site_viewshed_vector_generation failed…
Execution failed after 0.042 seconds
```

The faliure cascades from the point it first fails onwards. Not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue. Turns out, during the **Viewshed** step of the above model the algorithm generates a temp raster file of approx 8 GB per point that I run it for. This temp file is not deleted until QGIS is closed. Hence, the process fails once there is insufficient storage.

Resolved this by moving the task to a server with sufficient storage capacity and by breaking points into multiple batches.